# VBA: delete borders from floating images in ms-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, shapes

I have this code to put a border on all images in my Word document. Inline shapes as floating shapes. Works fine. All images have a border. But my images on the first page (like Logo) also have a border.

Can anyone help me out with code for deleting the borders around floating images on the front page? Or specific shapes?

Thank you.
Kem

Comment: This is not a "please write me some code"-Forum. But a little hint: Use "record macro" to create a macro which does the job. The have a look at your macro-code ;-)

Comment: If you have the code, please use the [edit] link below the question to copy/paste the code into your question. It's not possible for anyone to even begin to guess what's going on without the code as a basis.

Comment: @Kara, sorry. I wanted a hint in the right direction. But many times i see full code in the answers. 
It's not possible to start recording a macro and select a shape. Not even when a shape is already selected. Before I post a question on a forum, I always try to figure it out myself (like recording macro's). But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selection.Information(wdActivePageEnd) command can give you the current page number and in your case all you need to do is set the current selection point or working range to the top of the document ... and now you know you are on page 1.

The second challenge is selecting or setting a working range to only the first page. I use the built-in Bookmark "\Page".

The third challenge is identifying the type of shape and for that you use the Shape.Type property. If you are going after images remember they could be embedded or linked so you have to use the two property types.

Finally, in your questions you are asking how to remove borders. Well IMO you don't have to remove them, you only hide them.

Here is example code that you can study and figure out how to integrate with your existing code.

```
Sub RemoveBorders()
Dim rng As Word.Range, shp As Word.Shape
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
For Each shp In rng.ShapeRange
    If shp.Type = msoPicture Or shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
        shp.Line.Visible = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Rich. This works 100%. And thank you for your clear explanation.